# Parallels Desktop 12 - Disable Time Sync

Tags: parallels-desktop

Is there any way to disable the time sync on Parallels Desktop 12 ? Whenever I resume my VM - certain tools I have running see the time change and immediately kick into high gear to update themselves and I'd like to prevent that.

Comment: What's the VM's operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VM configuration, go to **Options** → **More Options** and set **Time** to **Do not sync**.

[image]

Comment: This is not always a reliable solution. I experienced some strange behavior like increasing the hour by one every minute in the guest if I didn't disable/unload Parallels' timesync daemon (i.e OS X)/service in the vm itself.